# Micronaut test: Execution failed for task ':compileTestGroovy'. > java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, spock, micronaut

I am new to micronaut and I am trying to implement spock test on my project. I am currently using `micronautVersion=2.5.13` and I am having my tests in `src/test/groovy/{package_name}`. I am trying to run this test :

```
import io.micronaut.context.ApplicationContext
import io.micronaut.context.env.Environment
import io.micronaut.runtime.EmbeddedApplication
import io.micronaut.test.extensions.spock.annotation.MicronautTest
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

import javax.inject.Inject

@MicronautTest
class EnvironmentDetectionSpec extends Specification {
    @Unroll
    void "test environment is detected automatically" () {
        given:
        ApplicationContext ctx = ApplicationContext.run()

        expect:
        ctx.environment.getActiveNames().contains(Environment.TEST)

        cleanup:
        ctx.close()
    }
}
```

on running the test I am getting this exception:

```
Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileTestGroovy'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:142)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:140)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:69)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:327)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:307)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:293)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:420)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:342)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at io.micronaut.ast.groovy.utils.AstAnnotationUtils$_getAnnotationMetadata_closure1.doCall(AstAnnotationUtils.groovy:54)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.apply(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.core.util.clhm.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.lambda$compute$0(ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.java:721)
        at io.micronaut.core.util.clhm.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.compute(ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.java:733)
        at io.micronaut.core.util.clhm.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.java:710)
        at io.micronaut.ast.groovy.utils.AstAnnotationUtils.getAnnotationMetadata(AstAnnotationUtils.groovy:53)
        at io.micronaut.ast.groovy.visitor.LoadedVisitor.matches(LoadedVisitor.groovy:114)
        at io.micronaut.ast.groovy.TypeElementVisitorTransform$_visit_closure1.doCall(TypeElementVisitorTransform.groovy:81)
        at io.micronaut.ast.groovy.TypeElementVisitorTransform.visit(TypeElementVisitorTransform.groovy:81)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:270)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.GroovyCompilerFactory$DaemonSideCompiler.execute(GroovyCompilerFactory.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.GroovyCompilerFactory$DaemonSideCompiler.execute(GroovyCompilerFactory.java:76)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerWorkAction.execute(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:135)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:49)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker.executeInClassLoader(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:43)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.IsolatedClassloaderWorker.run(IsolatedClassloaderWorker.java:49)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.IsolatedClassloaderWorker.run(IsolatedClassloaderWorker.java:30)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.run(WorkerDaemonServer.java:87)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.run(WorkerDaemonServer.java:56)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction$1.call(WorkerAction.java:138)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.WorkerLogEventListener.withWorkerLoggingProtocol(WorkerLogEventListener.java:41)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction.run(WorkerAction.java:135)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: io.micronaut.inject.annotation.internal.KotlinNullableMapper cannot be cast to io.micronaut.inject.annotation.AnnotationMapper
        at io.micronaut.inject.annotation.AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.<clinit>(AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:70)
        ... 33 more
```

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.0.0"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "1.5.4"
    id "groovy"
}

version = "0.1"
group = {groupName}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation ('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24')
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jdbc-hikari")
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jdbi")
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java:3.4.3'
    implementation 'io.micronaut:micronaut-inject:3.4.3'
    implementation 'io.github.crac.io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java:1.3.7'
//    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
//    implementation 'io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5:3.2.0'
//    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2'
    implementation 'redis.clients:jedis:2.8.2'
    implementation group: 'io.reactivex.rxjava2', name: 'rxjava', version: '2.2.19'
//    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.2'
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")

    // Testing dependencies
    testImplementation("org.spockframework:spock-core") {
        exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy", module: "groovy-all"
    }
    testImplementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    testImplementation "io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-spock"
}


application {
    mainClass.set("com.suvodip.panapplication.Application")
}
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("1.8")
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("1.8")
}

micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("spock2")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations({packageName})
    }
}
```

I have even tried to eliminate the junit from dependencies but still getting the same error. Would be really thankful if someone could help me here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I recommend to cleanup your `build.gradle` file, since you define a lots of dependencies that are automatically provided by the Micronaut `application` plugin.

```
plugins {
    id("groovy") 
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.0.0"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "1.5.4"
}

version = "0.1"
group = "com.example"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("spock2")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.suvodip.panapplication.*")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    // put your app specific dependencies here, but don't add any test deps such as Spock or JUnit
}


application {
    mainClass.set("com.suvodip.panapplication.Application")
}
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("11")
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("11")
}
```

Then I see you are using Micronaut CRAC, as far as I know this is only supported when using Micronaut 3.7+.

My recommendation is to start with a blank Micronaut 3.7.4, copy your Spock test into that project and run it. If this works, start adding your additional dependencies such as

- Postgres JDBC Driver
- JDBI
- …